# how to upload image to asw s3

Tags: ios, objective-c, amazon-s3

I am uploading image from the following code -

```
NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0);

 AmazonS3Client *s3Client = [[[AmazonS3Client alloc] initWithAccessKey:ACCESS_KEY_ID withSecretKey:SECRET_KEY] autorelease];

   s3Client.timeout = 240;
   NSString *bucketName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"test/images/"];
   NSString *imageName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"testimage.jpg"];

   S3PutObjectRequest *objReq = [[S3PutObjectRequest alloc] initWithKey:imageName inBucket:bucketName];
   objReq.contentType = @"image/jpeg";
   objReq.data = imageData;
   objReq.delegate = self;
   objReq.contentLength = [imageData length];
   [s3Client putObject:objReq];
```

I am getting following error -

S3Response.m|-[S3Response connection:didFailWithError:]|234|UserInfo.NSUnderlyingError = Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1003 "A server with the specified hostname could not be found." UserInfo=0xac62aa0 `{NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://test/images/.s3.amazonaws.com/testimage.jpg`

Please suggest me what i am doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in `bucketName` you are storing the path to the folder within your bucket. You need to only have your bucket name there.

It should be:
`https://bucketname.s3.amazonaws.com/test/images/testimage.jpg`

Your's is:
`https://test/images/.s3.amazonaws.com/testimage.jpg`

See the problem? test/images/.s3.amazonaws.com is not a valid domain name.

Comment: Thanks for the reply atomk,I am checking.